# How to use two queries inside merge statement

Tags: sql-server, merge, insert, sql-update, sql-server-2016

I have a table called `product` and its data as follows,

```
| ProductID | ProductName | Code | SortValue |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----------+
| 10        | AAA         | 13RT | 1         |
| 11        | BBB         | 14RT | 2         |
| 12        | CCC         | 15RT | 3         |
| 13        | DDD         | 16RT | 4         |
| 14        | EEE         | 17RT | 5         |
| 15        | FFF         | 19RT | 6         |
```

I wrote a merge query to insert product data as follows,

```
MERGE [product] AS target 
USING (SELECT @productName, @code) AS source (productname, code) 
      ON (target.code = source.code) 

WHEN matched THEN 
     UPDATE 
         SET productname = source.productname, 
             code = source.code,

WHEN NOT matched THEN 
     INSERT (productname, code, sortvalue) 
     VALUES (source.productname, source.code, 1) 

OUTPUT inserted.productid INTO @insertedTable;
```

You can see the product table has a column `SortValue` and each product has a sort value. I need to insert newly inserting product sort value as 1 and need to update the existing product's sort value by one. To do that, I wrote the following query.

```
UPDATE product
SET SortValue = sortvalue + 1
WHERE sortvalue >= 1;
```

I need to execute the above query before inserting new records. How can I do it, I apply it after the merge statement's  `NOT matched` part, but it makes an error. How can I sort this issue?